# LinkedIn automatic login using Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

Is it possible to create an automatic login script in Python? I have my LinkedIn account and I just want to automate my login.

Comment: can you not just use the "remember me" option?

Comment: Hey, no browser involved here to use the "remember me" option. I'm talking about the script.

Comment: You need to look at the SocialAuth APIs of any of your favourite programming languages. That is the whole idea behind what you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do your task. For a quick job done, I would use mechanize module.

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.open("https://www.linkedin.com/")
browser.select_form(name="login")

browser["session_key"] = "your_email"
browser["session_password"] = "your_password"
response = browser.submit()

print response.read()
```

Here's some good articles on mechanize module in case you are not familiar with it:

- [Python Mechanize cheat sheet](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/)
- [Browsing in Python with Mechanize](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/browsing-in-python-with-mechanize/)